# How to insert multiple GroupDescription?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've made an application that allow to get the live result of a match. 
Now the organization of each match is this:

```
Nation->League->Match list
```

So I've the `Nation` that is the container of the `League`, and the `League` is the container of the `Match`. What I did firstly was create a `XAML` structure that allow me to achieve a container result as said before:

```
<Window x:Class="GroupBox_Header.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GroupBox_Header"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Margin="10">
    <ListView Name="lvUsers">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Home Team" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding HomeTeam}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Away Team" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding AwayTeam}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>

        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemCount}" FontSize="22" Foreground="Green" FontWeight="Bold" FontStyle="Italic" Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                                <TextBlock Text=" Items" FontSize="22" Foreground="Silver" FontStyle="Italic" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                                        <Expander.Header>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding League}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Expander.Header>
                                        <ItemsPresenter />
                                    </Expander>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

How you can see there is a `ListView` that have a `GroupStyle` definition, in this I save all the `Nation`. You can try the `XAML` in your demo solution and check the result.

After this, I've created the struct that allow me to store the value:

```
public struct League 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public struct Country
{
    public string Name   { get; set; }
    public League League;
}
```

Is very pretty simple, a `League` struct for save all the leagues and a `Country` struct for the nations. I've valorized the `Country` in this way:

```
List<Country> items = new List<Country>();
            items.Add(new Country() { Name = "Italy", League = { Name = "Serie A"} });
            items.Add(new Country() { Name = "Italy", League = { Name = "Serie B" } });
            items.Add(new Country() { Name = "England", League = { Name = "Premiere League" } });
            items.Add(new Country() { Name = "Spain", League = { Name = "Primeira Division" } });
            lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;
```

So I actually have in list `Italy (2), England, Spain`. I then inserted `items` in the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` (the XAML control).

For create the header group as the `Nation` name, I've used a `CollectionView`:

```
CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupNations = new PropertyGroupDescription("Name");
```

This code allow me to create multiple headers, and the result is exactly what I want. I also did the same for the `League`, 'cause what I need is insert as a `sub-header` the `League` name in `Nation` container (header):

```
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupNations);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupCompetions = new PropertyGroupDescription("League");
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupNations);
```

but actually this is the result:

[image]

How you can see only the nation header appear, but the `League` header doesn't appear inside the `Nation` header. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you sure that is inside rather than under.  If you close Nation does it go away?

Comment: @Paparazzi Not sure about that, but what perhaps is another issue. Now I just can not print the name of the league.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can "fix" it by making `League` a property (add getter and setter - WPF bindings attach to properties, not fields), making the second group description group by `"League.Name"` instead of just `"League"` and make the second group style `TextBlock` binding bind to `Name`, not `League`.

Then you get this:

[image]

But I would say you are approaching this the wrong way and modeling your data in a really weird manner. If the `ListView` is intended to list `Matches`, then you should bind to a collection of `Match` objects (or a view over them), and each `Match` should reference its parent `League`, and each `League` should reference its parent `Country`.

Alternatively, use a tree instead of a list, and then have a `Country` with a collection of child `Leagues`, and each `League` with a collection of child `Matches`.

Or have both - a `League` that contains a collection of `Matches`, but each match has a parent `League` reference, and similar for `Country/League`.

The way it is in your code is kind of weird.

Also, I don't understand why you use structs for your objects instead of classes.

Changes to code behind (note, I am not saying this is a good way to do it, see above):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        List<Country> items = new List<Country>();
        items.Add(new Country() { Name = "Italy", League = new League { Name = "Serie A" } }); // Added "new League"
        items.Add(new Country() { Name = "Italy", League = new League { Name = "Serie B" } });
        items.Add(new Country() { Name = "England", League = new League { Name = "Premiere League" } });
        items.Add(new Country() { Name = "Spain", League = new League { Name = "Primeira Division" } });
        lvUsers.ItemsSource = items;

        CollectionView view = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(lvUsers.ItemsSource);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupNations = new PropertyGroupDescription("Name");
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupNations);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupCompetions = new PropertyGroupDescription("League.Name"); // Changed "League" to "League.Name"
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupCompetions); // Fixed the variable name here

        lvUsers.ItemsSource = view; // Added, you probably have it but didn't post it
    }
}

public struct League
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public struct Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public League League { get; set; } // added getter and setter
}
```

Changes to XAML, just 1 line:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Gray" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

`{Binding Name}` is `{Binding League}` in your original code.

Comment: so you have also added a new XAML `GroupStyle`? Could you show the code that have changed? I think that I'll replace the struct with the classes in the future. But why you don't advice the struct? The struct is a kind of lightweight data in comparison to a class. The result shold be like this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JuFRz.png The only things that I've added is the league.

Comment: @Dillinger I added the code... But this is not a good way to do it in the first place, this is why I didn't add it originally. It is a "hack".

Comment: thanks for this, what do you propose instead? I didn't found any control that allow me to do this, with vb.net and windows form I've created this custom control: http://pastebin.com/phrjz2un but now I can't reuse it.

Comment: @Dillinger well the simplest way would be to have just 1 class - `Match`, and it has a `string` property `Country` and a `string` property `League`. Then you create a view over a collection of `Matches` and group by `Country`, then by `League`. Unless you actually need a more complex model with classes for `Country` and `League`. If you do, I covered that in the answer.

Comment: just one thing, why the final result is different against the yours? => http://postimg.org/image/v9u9joqe9/ and this is my code => http://pastebin.com/X61gTmnX

Comment: The change to XAML I mention is for line 53 in your pastebin. Also, look at line 112 - `groupCompetions` not `groupNations`.

Comment: OT Question: Is possible display the sub-header a little to right to the parent header? In this way the user understand that the sub-header are contained in the Nation header. Like a TreeView.